# Why does measuring execution time with time module randomly output 0 seconds?

Tags: python

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
print('Running time :')
print(time.time()-start_time)
```

it's gotta be more than 0, so 0 should not come out.
This code sometimes outputs correctly like below.

```
Running time :
0.0009982585906982422
```

But sometimes it outputs 0 seconds.

```
Running time :
0.0
```

Why is this happening? I first suspected it being rounded, but judging from the correct result one, it seems even if they did, it wouldn't put out 0 as it has lots of digits below the point.

Answer (score 1):

The builtin `time` module is not meant to be used to time programs, especially such short ones. From the official [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html):

> The precision of the various real-time functions may be less than suggested by the units in which their value or argument is expressed. E.g. on most Unix systems, the clock “ticks” only 50 or 100 times a second.

To precisely time your program, use the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) which is meant for it, and takes care of some details like disabling garbage collection etc... to get a more precise timing.

```py
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('print("hello")', number=1000)
0.14811120001832023
```

Comment: Thanks, but i got one more problem, could you take a look at the question again?

Comment: Are you surprised because you get exactly 0 ? Most likely you code is so fast that it takes less than the available precision (~1 ms), but that time varies obviously depending on what you system does elsewhere. So you get 0 or 1 tick randomly, which is normal behavior.